# AddDictionary object to list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects:

```
public List<IdNamePair> Languages
{
    get { return languages; }
    set { languages = value; }
}
```

How do you add to the Languages list above from a dictionary of the same `IdNamePair`?

```
protected Dictionary<int, List<IdNamePair>> CountryLanguages { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
subjectBaseInfo.Languages = CountryLanguages;
```

But get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' To
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

`IdNamePair` contains `Id` and `Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two types are different. `subjectBaseInfo.Languages` is simply a single `List<IdNamePair>`, whereas `CountryLanguages` is a series of `List<IdNamePair>` indexed by an `int`.

So to do they assignment you have a couple of possibilities.

If I assume that `subjectBaseInfo` also has an `Id` property then you might be wanting to do this:

```
subjectBaseInfo.Languages = CountryLanguages[subjectBaseInfo.Id];
```

However, if `subjectBaseInfo` doesn't have an `Id` then you might want to get all of the `IdNamePair` from all of the lists in `CountryLanguages` as a new single list. In that case you can do this:

```
subjectBaseInfo.Languages = CountryLanguages.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: The linq query is what worked for me as I wanted all the items from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is the expected one. You cannot assign a dictionary to a variable, whose type is a list.

That you might need is the following (with the correct key value):

```
subjectBaseInfo.Languages = CountryLanguages[0];
```

The `CountryLanguages[0]` is the value for the key 0. The value that is corresponded with this key as every other key in this dictionary, is a `List<IdNamePair>` object. The latter is that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide key to `Dictionary`. Like this:

```
subjectBaseInfo.Languages = CountryLanguages[3]
```

Or other `int` key you used when populated your Dictionary object